# Get content of first paragraph

Tags: php

I am working on a small php script I have an html code like this :

```
<p>text1</p> <p>text2</p> <p>text3</p>
```

Is it possible to use php to get only the content of the first paragraph which is text1 ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Have tried simple php dom but i didnt manage to get the right code

Comment: please, show your code and result of it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is possible:

```
$text = '<p>text1</p> <p>text2</p> <p>text3</p>';
$text = preg_replace('/<\/p>[ ]{1,}<p>/', '</p><p>', $text);
$splitedText = explode('</p>', $text);
var_dump(substr($splitedText[0],3));
```

I Hope this helps!